# Printing asterisks - java/text files

Tags: java

**Sorry for the poorly worded question, I was in a hurry this morning because class was ending.**

--

```
final int maxS = height;
for (int row = 1; row <= maxS; row ++)
{
    for (int star = 1; star <= maxS; star++)
        System.out.print("* ");
    System.out.println();
}
```

I need this to be the output:

```
* * * * * 
* * * * 
* * * 
* * 
*
```

So the height is the number of rows, which is 5. I could get this

```
* 
* * 
* * * 
* * * * 
* * * * *
```

with a similar code to above, but it didn't work for me. I tried to get the inverse, but it didn't work.

Comment: You're getting a square, right? Try `star <= (maxS - row + 1)` for the first version and `star <= row` for the second.

Comment: This seems to be a lazy attempt at an _easy_ homework... The code is almost OK, there are only small things to change there. If you attended the classes, it should not be very difficult to interpret the code you see. Understand it, and write it out in plain English (or your mother tongue, that is even better), and then see where it needs adjusting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```java
int maxS = height;
for (int row = 1; row <= maxS; row ++)
{
    for (int star = maxS - row + 1; star >= 1; star--)
    System.out.print("* ");
    System.out.println();
}
```

You have to think step by step. What happens at each outer loop, and each inner loop. It is very easy actually. If you cannot get it working, you should manually go through each loop on paper. You want it to decrease at each iteration, so you have to use `--` instead of `++`.

Comment: single expression blocks without curly braces are ok, but should be indented to be more clear. (I cannot edit it myself, as “edits must be et least 6 characters… :dough:)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    final int maxS = 10;

    for (int row = 1; row <= maxS; row ++) {
        for (int star=maxS; star >= row; star--) {
            System.out.print("* ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

With your actual code, you will get a square, here is an example on how you can achieve it:

I've replaced the first `for` by:

```
for (int row = maxS; row >= 1; row--)
```

and the second `for` by:

```
for (int star = 1; star <= row; star++)
```

```
public static void main(String[] arv) throws Exception {
    final int maxS = height;
    for (int row = maxS; row >= 1; row--) {
        for (int star = 1; star <= row; star++) {
            System.out.print("* ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int row = maxS; row > 0; row--) {
    for (int star = 1; star <= maxS-row; star++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (int star = row; star >0; star--) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    
    System.out.println(); 
}
```

Comment: This does not produce the desired output.